# Sql script, create a database

Tags: mysql

I have the next file: create_mysql.sql

> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS
>   playence_media;    CREATE DATABASE
>   playence_media; USE playence_media;
>   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO
>   'media'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY
>   'media' WITH GRANT OPTION;

But I don't know how to create this database. I would like to do it with my terminal, no other graphics interfaces.   Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

# mysql < create_mysql.sql

Comment: The same error    ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: This is not "the same error" as you didn't specify one in the original post, but you obviously need to supply valid login parameters if necessary.

Read the mysql command manual.

Answer (score 5):

Using MySQL's command line client:

```
mysql -h <host> -u <username> -p < create_mysql.sql
```

You can ommit the `-h <host>` part if the server runs on your localhost.

Comment: Error message:

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'slosada'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Althoug using password i have the same error

Comment: -p alone will prompt for the password, use -p<password> (no whitespace in between) to provide it in-line.